How can I print this pattern
Problem statement:

You are given an integer n, representing the side length of a rhombus. Your task is to write a program to print the pattern of the sides and diagonals of the rhombus.
INPUT
The only line of the input contains a single integer n, representing the side length of a rhombus.
OUTPUT
Print the diagonals and sides of a rhombus.
Sample Input: 5
Sample Output:
    *    
   ***   
  * * *  
 *  *  * 
*********
 *  *  * 
  * * *  
   ***   
    *    


I tried this code but I'm unable to print the vertical bar of Rhombus.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    
    cin >> n;

    // Upper half of the rhombus
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        // Print spaces
        for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) {
            cout << " ";
        }

        // Print asterisks and spaces
        for (int j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++) {
            if (j == 1 || j == 2 * i - 1 || i == n) {
                cout << "*";
            } else {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    // Lower half of the rhombus
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
        // Print spaces
        for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) {
            cout << " ";
        }

        // Print asterisks and spaces
        for (int j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++) {
            if (j == 1 || j == 2 * i - 1 || i == 1) {
                cout << "*";
            } else {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


Unrelated to your problem but prefer to loop from zero to less than max, e.g. for (int i =0; i < n; ++i). Not only conventional, also easier and will work with array and container indices.

If j ranges from 1 to 2 * i - 1, the middle is at (1 + 2 * i - 1)/2 or just i. Did you mean to check if i == j instead of i==n ?

Giving more descriptive names to concepts in your program will help you spot this. eg the "vertical bar" check would simply be j == (begin + end) / 2. Crystal clear and impossible to fuck up.

Simply always print a '*' at position n/2.

Build up the shape in memory, before printing : https://onlinegdb.com/-5vDjBqSc

If you index the rows and columns from -n+1 to n-1, then the stars appear when either coordinate is 0, or the sum or difference of the two coordinates is n-1 or -n+1. Yielding this relatively concise code:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 8;
    --n;
    for (int i = -n; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = -n; j <= n; j++) {
            cout << ((i == 0 || j == 0 || abs(i - j) == n || abs(i + j) == n) ? "*" : " ");
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

The code uses a fixed n, but you can obviously change it to respond to input.

Using meaningful names for your variables would help. We can think of left, mid and right, each representing a position for an asterisk on a line. The middle line will be exception to this, having a solid line.
A recursive solution comes to mind, where before and after each recursive call you print the same line. The base case is when left is 1, and then a solid line is printed:
void line(int left, int mid, int right) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= right; i++) {
        std::cout << (left == 1 || i == left || i == mid || i == right ? '*' : ' '); 
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void rhombus_slice(int left, int mid, int right) {
    line(left, mid, right);
    if (left <= 1) return;
    rhombus_slice(left - 1, mid, right + 1);
    line(left, mid, right);
}

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    
    rhombus_slice(n, n, n);
}


I see you try to mark multiple answers as accepted. That is not possible. You can only mark one ;-)

A rhombus is a a quadrilateral all of whose sides have the same length.
The definition does not say anything about the angle sizes, so that may be varied, but I shall assume that its "top" will be in the middle and the sides open downward by increasing/decreasing their position by 1 each time. So you have three parts:

first part
middle section
second part

Input is N
So the first question is: how long will be the middle section?
Since we have N lines in the first part, that means that we have 1 (the middle) + N (left) + N (right). Therefore the answer is 2N + 1
Hence, if we start coordinates from 0, then the middle is N characters away.
Let's therefore draw the first half:
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int left = N - i;
    int right = N + i;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2 * N + 1; j++) {
        cout << ((i == left) || (i == right) || (i == N)) ? '*' : ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}

Now, let's draw the middle (this will be easy):
for (int i = 0; i < 2 * N + 1; i++) {
    cout << '*';
}
cout << endl;

And let's do it for the bottom too:
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int left = i;
    int right = 2 * N - i;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2 * N + 1; j++) {
        cout << ((i == left) || (i == right) || (i == N)) ? '*' : ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}

Basically we are consistently displaying on the specified lines. Code was untested, please let me know if anything does not click.
